# Install gcc 6 under ubuntu 19.10

Tags: apt, gcc

Is it possible to install `gcc-6` on Ubuntu 19.10? Any way I can include it in default repo or install through `deb` package?

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan

$ sudo apt-get install gcc-6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gcc-6 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gcc-6' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: gcc-6 is no longer supported; https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/